# KL_feature tracking not working

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

Hey guys i don't know why but due to some reason i am facing problem in implementing this code below i have already gone through all the post on various website to get rid of this problem but most of them were based on syntactical error which in case of mine is not :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#parameters for ShiTomasi corner detection
st_params=dict(maxCorners = 100,qualityLevel = 0.3,minDistance = 7,blockSize = 7)
#parameters for Lucas Kanade Optical Flow
lk_params=dict(winSize=(15,15),maxLevel=2,criteria=(cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))
#Take first frame and find corners in it
ret,first_frame=cap.read()
first_gray=cv2.cvtColor(first_frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
p0=cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(first_gray,mask = None,**st_params)
#create mask
mask=np.zeros_like(first_frame)

while True:
  (ret,frame) = cap.read()
  #frame_gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  cv2.imshow('k',frame)
  k=cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff
 #calculate optical flow
 pl,st,err= cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(first_gray, frame_gray, p0, None,**lk_params)


#Good point selection
good_new=pl[st == 1]
good_old=p0[st == 1]

#draw the tracks
for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
    a,b = new.ravel()
    c,d = old.ravel()
    mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d),(0,255,0), 2)
    frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,(0,0,255),-1)
img = cv2.add(frame,mask)

#cv2.imwrite('detectedframe_{0}.jpg'.format(i),img)
cv2.imshow('k',img)
k=cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
if k == 27:
    break

first_gray=frame_gray.copy()
p0=good_new.reshape(-1,1,2)

cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
cap.release()
```

its given an error messange:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/vasu/Documents/opencv-2.4.13/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 261
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "LK_OpticalFlow.py", line 42, in <module>
cv2.imshow('k',img)
cv2.error: /home/vasu/Documents/opencv-2.4.13/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

after doing multiple hit and trial i have came to the conclusion that error is occurring due to cv2.line and cv2.circle as cv2.imshow is working fine with mask and frame when these line are commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey guys it seems my problem has been solved i think in opencv 2.4.13 there is some changes. i just changed

mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d),(0,255,0), 2)
frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,(0,0,255),-1)
to 
cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d),(0,255,0), 2)
cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,(0,0,255),-1)